# Can someone explain this code about web routes in PHP

Tags: php, routes

This is the code under routes -> web.php.

You do not have to explain all of the line just take starting point in of them.

[image]

I have no idea what this code does.

Comment: I've never used Laravel, but I thing reading up about [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like Laravel.

It's a list of entrypoints to your application. It tells Laravel what should happen if the application is called on a specific "endpoint", e.g. "https://yourdomain.tld/counter".

Let's take the first line, word by word:

```
Route::get('/counter', [ExampleController::class, 'counter']);
```

- `Route` refers to the Route class in Laravel. When using this we are
  defining a route instruction to Laravel-
- `::get` this refers to which "HTTP verb" we are listening on. Other HTTP verbs except for GET is POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE.
- `'/counter'` this refers to the URL that must match this route.
- `[ExampleController::class,` this tells Laravel which controller class the route must be resolved in
- `, 'counter']);` this tells Laravel which *method* inside the controller class the route must be handled in.

So that line basically tells Laravel that "when a client calls https://yourdomain.tld/count with a GET call, the code that must be run is the method `counter()` inside the ExampleController class.